# Elasticsearch inserting duplicate data?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch

When I connect Elasticsearch to my MySQL database using this [JDBC](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc).

I want it to fetch regularly to get the most recent changes from the database but it looks like from the logs that it copies all data on every iteration instead of just the most recent changes. Though when I do a search using the REST API I can't see any duplicates. Is this normal?

The log says this every minute (with `rows` increasing with ~3000 each time):

> [INFO][river.jdbc.RiverMetrics  ] pipeline org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline@273cf2ca complete: river jdbc/items metrics: 24745 rows, 61.24885239965816 mean, (56.52859885706843 11.685682148116433 3.916887460538012), ingest metrics: elapsed 0 seconds, 291,25 KB bytes, 12.0 bytes avg, 1,061 MB/s
>   [2015-05-20 22:22:15,607][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Gideon] low disk watermark [15%] exceeded on [6TQNFDctRSaYVFyKjQahJA][Gideon] free: 26.6gb[11.4%], replicas will not be assigned to this node

This is what I use to start the JDBC

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/items/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "123",
        "sql" : "select items.id as _id from items",
        "index": "items",
        "type": "item",
        "schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *"
    }
}'
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal. ES always will reindex all rows returned from sql query.

You can check `_version` field of your documents and see that it's increased after every river execution.

Indeed, you should avoid using rivers because they are [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers).

Comment: However, the JDBC river is [future proof](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#this-plugin-is-future-proof) according to its authors as it can be used as a standalone module, which is one of the ways to go forward according to the "deprecating rivers" article.

Comment: I would add that Elasticsearch requests are idempotent, that's why there is no duplicate even if you index the same document hundred of times